# how to get second last and last value in a string after separator in python

Tags: python

In Python, how do you get the last and second last element in string ?
string `"client_user_username_type_1234567"`
expected output : `"type_1234567"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
>>> s = "client_user_username_type_1234567"
>>> '_'.join(s.split('_')[-2:])
'type_1234567'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `re.findall`:

```
import re
s = "client_user_username_type_1234567"
result = re.findall('[a-zA-Z]+_\d+$', s)[0]
```

Output:

```
'type_1234567'
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no set function that will do this for you, you have to use what Python gives you and for that I present:

[split](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) [slice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation) and [join](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)

```
"_".join("one_two_three".split("_")[-2:])
```

In steps:

1. Split the string by the common separator, "_"

   s.split("_")
2. Slice the list so that you get the **last two elements** by using a negative index

   s.split("_")[-2:]
3. Now you have a list composed of the last two elements, now you have to merge that list again so it's like the original string, with separator "_".

   "_".join("one_two_three".split("_")[-2:])

That's pretty much it. Another way to investigate is through regex.